# When I am trying to import a custom hook function I am getting a typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to import my custom hook function(RegisterUser) on my register page. but when I am trying to import like this `const { RegisterUser } = UseFirebase()` I am getting an error which is `const RegisterUser: any Property 'RegisterUser' does not exist on type 'readonly [(email: string, password: string, name: string, history: any) => Promise<void>]'.`

**This is my custom hook function.**

```
export default function UseFirebase() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const auth = getAuth()


    // REGISTER WITH EMAIL AND PASSWORD
    const RegisterUser = async (email: string, password: string, name: string, history: any) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

        const newUser = {
            email,
            displayName: name
        };

        setUser(newUser);
        setError('')

        // Pass userCredential.user instead of auth.currentUser
        updateProfile(userCredential.user, {
            displayName: name
        }).then(() => { }).catch((error) => { });
        history.replace('/');
    }

    return [RegisterUser] as const

}
```

Can anyone help me, please? How can I solve the error?

Comment: Quick notice, you shouldn't update your question with the correct answer, because now it doesn't make any sense for someone reading your question, as it won't have any problems. You should leave the initial code you wrote and just accept the correct answer.

Comment: I rolled back you edits so it's correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you typed your component as `React.FunctionComponent<IUseFirebaseProps>` but you returning `[RegisterUser] as const` and `RegisterUser` is not the correct return type for `React.FunctionComponent<IUseFirebaseProps>` or `React.ReactElement<any, any> | null`.

If you are trying to make a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), you should remove `React.FunctionComponent<IUseFirebaseProps>` and `React.ReactElement<any, any> | null` which aren't necessary in a custom hook.

Also, a custom hook don't need to receive props of the type `React.PropsWithChildren<IUseFirebaseProps>`, maybe just use `IUseFirebaseProps` as a normal function parameter.

I'm guessing here, but you probably need something like this:

```js
// type for the RegisterUserFunction
type RegisterUserFunction = (
  email: string,
  password: string,
  name: string,
  history: any
) => Promise<void>;

const UseFirebase = (
  props: IUseFirebaseProps, // it's not the props from a component, but more like a normal function parameter
  context?: any
): [RegisterUserFunction] => {
  // other hooks

  // REGISTER WITH EMAIL AND PASSWORD
  const RegisterUser: RegisterUserFunction = async (
    email: string,
    password: string,
    name: string,
    history: any
  ) => {
    // your function
  };

  return [RegisterUser]; // no need to use as const
};
```

Comment: Love it, Thank you so much. another problem I am facing is when I am trying to import RegisterUser on another page I am getting an error. I am importing like this `const { RegisterUser } = UseFirebase()` & The error is `const RegisterUser: any
Property 'RegisterUser' does not exist on type '[RegisterUserFunction]'.`

Comment: @Jerin You are using `{ RegisterUser }` where it expects `UseFirebase` to return an object, but it returns an array, so you should do `[RegisterUser]` with `[]`. If that helped, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted, thanks!